# Is the Google Translate Phrasebook Syncing not available in the iOS app?

Tags: ios, google, google-sync

Is the Google Translate Phrasebook Syncing not available in the iOS app?

I can't find my phrasebook listing. It seems the list on the iPhone is not stored online as for the web. I suspect they implement it for Android only.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the Google Translate App for iOS does not synchronize with your account.  The phrasebook only synchronizes in the web and Android versions.